# Export MySQL Table to XML for use with .NET system.data.DataTable ReadXML()

Tags: c#, php, mysql, xml

I have a situation where I need to export a MySQL table with schema and data to XML on a server, and import that XML into a System.Data.DataTable using [DataTable.ReadXML()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfxbc3by(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm doing the client-side work and someone else is doing the server-side work. The server-side is using PHP. I've read that using **FOR XML** on the MySQL query will output results in XML, but it's unclear how to get a XML Document with the table's schema that is compatible with DataTable.ReadXML(). Has anyone got a simple way to handle the PHP side of  this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what .NET language are you using? also note that MySQL and SQL-Server are different technologies.  SQL-Server specifically refers to Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: C#, and I am aware that they're different technologies.